# Rails Test Fails - Hartl Tutorial Ch. 6 Page 256/257

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

According to Hartl uniqueness: is infered by Ruby as true in ruby.rb.
Nevertheless my test only passes when I set it to false explicetly.
Can you spot the error?

The REGEX part is correct - it is only about this line:
 uniqueness: case_sensitive: false

Test:

```
test "email addresses should be unique" do
    duplicate_user = @user.dup
    duplicate_user.email = @user.email.upcase
    @user.save
    assert_not duplicate_user.valid?
end
```

Model: (ruby.rb)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                  format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                  uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try enveloping `case_sensitive` in brackets, like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                  format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                  uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

More info on `uniqueness` [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did so but this did not help. Thanks for the link - I will have a look.

Comment: According to your link on uniqueness I tried "uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }" which also fails

Comment: That's interesting. I just checked Hartl's implementation and `uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }` should work. Can you post how you created `@user` in your test?

Comment: require 'test_helper'

    class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  
 def setup
  @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
 end

Comment: Have you tried saving the initial @user to the test database by calling `create` instead of `new`? I think this should work, because when the `duplicate_user` is being saved, it has nothing to compare to when Rails looks in the test db for records to compare for uniqueness. Hope that does it.

Comment: Is it possible that the error arises because I used MySQL instead on SQLight?

Comment: Oh that could be a possibility. Did you make sure to update your `config/database.yml` test adapter to use mysql instead of sqlite?

Comment: Sorry about that - I just saw in config.yml that I'm using SQLite3 not only for testing but also for the application....

Comment: It's no problem :) Let me know if that worked so I could update the answer for anyone else who might see this in the future.

Comment: now it works - nothing changed afaik - can't tell why. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

the problem may be because you might have included the line
attr_accessor :name, :email in the user model.

If you remove that line then there should not be any error.

Hope this will help